# Absolute align top of element in column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 2 columns side by side. The left column contains HTML outside of my control. The right side needs to display a comment box which would ideally be aligned with the text that is clicked on the left hand side.

How can you absolute position the top of an element relative to a non-sibling?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ark51cLu/4/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="box1">
        <div class="inner-html-box">
          <p onclick="clicked(event)">Item 1</p>
          <p onclick="clicked(event)">Item 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div id="comment-box" class="box2">Item 1 comments</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see my answer i think so it works like you want @geejay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want like this,

add `px` to top value like,

```
box2.style.top = top + "px";
```

```js
function clicked(ev) {
    var top = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var box2 = document.querySelector('.box2');
    box2.style.top = top + "px";
    box2.innerText = ev.target.innerText;
    console.log(top);
}
```

```css
.left{
  float: left;
  width:75%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width:25%;
}

.box1{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box2{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="left">
   <div class="box1">
   <p onclick="clicked(event)">Blah 1</p>
      <p onclick="clicked(event)">Blah 2</p>
   </div>
  </div>
<div class="right">
 <div class="box2">Blah 1 stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`top` expects a length value ([top on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)):

```
box2.style.top = top + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't tag this with jQuery, here's a vanilla js version.

```js
const box1 = document.querySelector('.box1')
const box2 = document.querySelector('.box2')

box1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let top;
  if(e.target.nodeName = "P") {
    top = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top
    box2.style.transform = `translateY(${top}px)`
  } else {
    return
  }
})
```

```css
.left{
  float: left;
  width:75%;
  
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width:25%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.box1{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box2{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: transform .3s
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="box1">
      <p>Blah 1</p>
      <p>Blah 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="box2">Blah 1 stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```